# Elasticsearch returns results greater than specified in range

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm use **Elasticsearch** (Version: 6.8.4) with **MongoDB** (4.0.3)

I want find all the documents where price between 1 and 800 and sale_date is greater than Date.now(), but I have problem with my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": {
        "term": { 
          "sold_out": false 
        },
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "range": {
                "sale_date": {
                  "gt": Date.now()
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "price": {
                  "gt": 1,
                  "lte": 800
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 10,
  "size": 200
}
```

It's query returns me results with products where some of them have price greater than 800

Price field stored in Elasticsearch as **long**

**Whant I'm try:**

- use from: to: and got the same results
- change "should" to "must" in filter and it's returns empty results
- remove from query { "range": { "sale_date": { "gt": Date.now(), } }
  } and it's returns **right** results!

**What I'm doing wrong ?**

Comment: You want all the documents where price is less or equal than 800 AND sale_date is greater than Date.now? What version of elasticsearch are you using? Please try to include as much information as possible when asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the uneccessary nesting ofthe two bool objects, try having all the clauses in the same "bool" field like this.

Remeber that with **must** a document must have the term you are making a comparison on to be included in the result, with **should** a match will only improve the score, if the condition is met, so in a certain sense **must is like AND** and **should similar to an OR**.

In your example changing the filter from should to must made the query return nothing maybe because you don't have any element that has both the date and price you want, or maybe it was the problem was the bool nesting.

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "range": {
          "sale_date": {
            "gt": Date.now()
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "range": {
          "price": {
            "gt": 1,
            "lte": 800
          }
        }
      }],
        "filter": {
        "term": {
          "sold_out": false
        },
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 10,
  "size": 200
}
```

This will only get the elements with price lte 800 and sale_date gt Date.now().

Answer (score -1):

Change Date().now() to "gt": "now/d".